# CodeDom compiler having trouble accessing dll's in temp

Tags: .net, vb.net, codedom

```
Public Function GenerateScript(code As String) As IScript
    Using provider As New VBCodeProvider()
        Dim parameters As New CompilerParameters()
        parameters.GenerateInMemory = True
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
        Dim interfaceNamespace As String = GetType(IScript).Namespace
        Dim codeArray() As String = New String() {"Imports " & interfaceNamespace & Environment.NewLine & code}
        Dim results As CompilerResults = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, codeArray)
        Return CType(results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("Script"), IScript)
    End Using
End Function
```

I am using the code above to run a string that may change over time. When I run this however, I get this error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\zjf\AppData\Local\Temp\ykujgxkp.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. Could anyone help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: `The system cannot find the file specified`-isn't it obvious that the file is not there ? if it's there, then why not run the application as administrator and see if problem exists ?

Comment: same thing happens when run with admin

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the section where you have to implement the `dll` file into your application, try adding this to your code :

```
Parameters.EmbeddedResources.Add("C:\Users\zjf\AppData\Local\Temp\ykujgxkp.dll")
Parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(New String() {"System.dll", "System.Drawing.dll", "System.Windows.Forms.dll", "System.Management.dll", "C:\Users\zjf\AppData\Local\Temp\ykujgxkp.dll"})
```

So your final code should be something like this :

```
Public Function GenerateScript(code As String) As IScript
    Using provider As New VBCodeProvider()
        Dim parameters As New CompilerParameters()
        parameters.GenerateInMemory = True
        Parameters.EmbeddedResources.Add("C:\Users\zjf\AppData\Local\Temp\ykujgxkp.dll")
        Parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(New String() {"System.dll", "System.Drawing.dll", "System.Windows.Forms.dll", "System.Management.dll", "C:\Users\zjf\AppData\Local\Temp\ykujgxkp.dll"})
        Dim interfaceNamespace As String = GetType(IScript).Namespace
        Dim codeArray() As String = New String() {"Imports " & interfaceNamespace & Environment.NewLine & code}
        Dim results As CompilerResults = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, codeArray)
        Return CType(results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("Script"), IScript)
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Actually, it's not because I haven't imported it. Whenever I execute the code, the name of the dll changes therefore it cannot be imported. I think that the dll is only a temporary dll and isn't a static one. Furthermore that dll or any dll similar cannot be found in the temp folder.

Comment: Anyone have an answer?